# how to set individual session maxAge in express?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I understand that you can set the maxAge when starting up the app as follows:

```
connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }})
```

However, i would like to implement something along the lines of "remember me" setting, how would i go about doing that?

Thanks a lot :)

Jason

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can set either `expires` or `maxAge` on the individual cookie belonging to the current user:

```
// This user should log in again after restarting the browser
req.session.cookie.expires = false;

// This user won't have to log in for a year
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

See [connect session documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).